# Efficiently converting equations into coefficient matrix

Tags: replacement

I have a list of `n` linear equations in variables `state[i]` for `i = 1, ..., n` and `outcome[j]` for `j = 1,2,3`. To solve these for `state[i]`, I convert the equation list into two matrices and use `LinearSolve`:

```
outcomeMatrix = -eqnList /. {state -> ({0, 0, 0} &), outcome -> (UnitVector[3, #] &)};
coeffMatrix = eqnList /. {state -> (Evaluate@UnitVector[Length@eqnList, #] &),
    outcome -> (Evaluate@Table[0, Length@eqnList] &)};
soluMatrix = LinearSolve[coeffMatrix, outcomeMatrix];
```

The problem is that `coeffMatrix` takes way too long to compute. In one example with 4633 equations, the three matrices took 1.42, 18.9, and 1.53 seconds, respectively. How can I speed it up?

Edit: in the above example, `coeffMatrix` is 97.6% zeros (`0` or `0.`). Not sure if that helps.

Edit: the equations are `eqn == 0` for each member of `eqnList`. Example:

```
eqnList={state[1] - 0.5 state[2] - 0.5 state[3],
    -0.51 outcome[1] + 0.755 state[2] - 0.245 state[3],
    -0.15 outcome[1] - 0.15 outcome[2] - 0.35 outcome[3] + 0.65 state[3]};
```

Comment: @yarchik My code is working, and I'm using it to get results I can independently verify. How would I use `SparseArray`? I can see how it might be useful to speed up the linear solve, but the problem is computing `coeffMatrix` quickly.

Comment: @yarchik Huh, I wouldn't have thought a bunch of zeros would take so much time. The `state` and `outcome` variables are in the equations in `eqnList`.

Comment: What is `eqnList`?

Comment: @cvgmt Hm, I see how that could cause some confusion - I was about to write "the equation list", but of course the members are not actual equations. The equations are `eqn == 0` for each member of `eqnList`. I'll edit OP.

Comment: @yarchik Added a small example, not sure how useful it is. The code to generate `eqnList` is long.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`CoefficientArrays`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CoefficientArrays) for this:

```
outcomeMatrix = CoefficientArrays[eqnList, Array[outcome, 3]][[2]];
coeffMatrix = CoefficientArrays[eqnList, Array[state, 3]][[2]];
```

[`CoefficientArrays`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CoefficientArrays) returns [`SparseArray`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SparseArray) objects by default. You can convert to normal matrices using [`Normal`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Normal):

```
Normal @ outcomeMatrix
Normal @ coeffMatrix
```

> {{0, 0, 0}, {-0.51, 0, 0}, {-0.15, -0.15, -0.35}}

> {{1., -0.5, -0.5}, {0, 0.755, -0.245}, {0, 0, 0.65}}

This agrees with your code:

```
outcomeMatrix = -eqnList /. {state -> ({0, 0, 0} &), outcome -> (UnitVector[3, #] &)}
coeffMatrix = eqnList /. {state -> (Evaluate@UnitVector[Length@eqnList, #] &), outcome -> (Evaluate@Table[0, Length@eqnList] &)}
```

> {{0., 0., 0.}, {0.51, 0., 0.}, {0.15, 0.15, 0.35}}

> {{1., -0.5, -0.5}, {0., 0.755, -0.245}, {0., 0., 0.65}}

Comment: Thank you! Times went from 1.42, 18.9, 1.53 to 0.79, 0.20, 0.38.